# How to convert string 'yyyymmddThhmmssZ' to string 'yyyymmddhhmmss' in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to convert the string date format.

Before convert value "`20171201T120000Z`".

After convert value(expected value) "`20171201120000`"

Is there the best way?
I don't want to use 'replace' method. like this

```
beforeValue.replace(/([a-zA-Z])/g, '')
```

It is seems to be not smart.

Comment: string replacing as you said seems best idea for me.

Comment: Use this regex `replace(/[TZ]/g, '')`.

Answer (score 1):

```
str = str.slice(0, 8) + str.slice(9,15);
```

is another way to do it without using replace

Comment: possible if you find it feel free to edit it i may have miscounted

Answer (score 1):

A smarter solution without `replace` :-)

```js
let a = '20171201T120000Z';
let b = a.split('').filter(x => x.match(/\d/)).join('');
console.log(b);
```

Comment: Uhh, huh. At last some else didn't think so >_<

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use `replace()`, then you could simply use `substr()`, which is faster according to [this](https://jsperf.com/replace-or-substr) jsPerf:

```js
let d = '20171201T120000Z'
console.log(d.substr(0, 8) + d.substr(9, 6))
```